# Adding a waveform on top of an LED driver signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, signal, sound

My Background:
I have a basic understanding of electronics from undergraduate physics courses and a few high-level digital electronics courses, but basically zero knowledge of anything analog/actually building circuits. The term "coupling capacitor" was new for me not too long ago, if that helps give some perspective.

I recently saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwX4JZ7Wo9Q) and I thought it was super cool. I want to create my own version of it and instead of using an MP3 player, I'd like to use a waveform generator (specifically the [AD9833](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9833.pdf)) so that I can better control the light/sound emitted from several LEDs (an array 16 RGB LEDS to be exact) with an Arduino Nano. I'm assuming I can't just connect the output of the waveform generator in parallel with an [LED driver](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5955.pdf) (see below schematic) like the guy does with the MP3 player and battery... but I'm not really sure what I'd use instead to accomplish this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwkeo0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm making my question a bit more specific. I was imagining doing something like in the below schematic.

Would a summing amplifier work for this purpose? From the TI schematic, the driver tries to maintain a set current rather than a set voltage (if I've understood it correctly). Would I be safe connecting the circuit up like so?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxdsYZ.png)</sup>

I reread the [TI schematic](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5955.pdf) and it seems like the LED Driver is open-drain (please correct me if I'm mistaken). Also, I found out that Op-Amps sort of separate the inputs from the outputs (very little current flows) if there's no connection between the terminals, so it would seem the LED driver would be problematic in the above schematic where it is. My next idea is to add the signal to a 5V supply that would be the main power for the LEDs. What do you guys think?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1VUs0.png)</sup>

In response to @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75's comment about specs:
I'm hoping to use RGB LEDs similar to [these](https://www.kingbright.com/attachments/file/psearch/000/00/00/L-154A4SUREQBFZGC(Ver.9A).pdf). For simplicity, I'd like to design something for only the red component. It has an average forward voltage of 1.9 to a max of 2.5V. The signal I'd like to superimpose on the 5V supply would ideally be within human hearing range (20Hz-20kHz), but I can live with a smaller range if I have to. The amplitude would be limited by the waveform generator ([AD9833](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9833.pdf)) which on the spec sheet says 0.038V to .65V. I'm not really sure how to give a spec on noise (is it just an SNR?). I built a circuit similar to the one in the video using an lm386, a solar panel and an LED. I strobed the LED with a couple note frequencies (440Hz for an A, etc) and in a dark room it sounded pretty clear. I'm not sure I fully understand what I [read here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an148fa.pdf), but it seems like  op-amp noise frequencies only appear at high frequencies (MHz range), where a person's ear won't really be able to hear it. My target SNR would be something around 30dB, I'm not overly concerned with a little distortion as the goal is to create an instrument.

Comment: *but I've read there can be issues with oscillations using op-amps* Sure, if you use an opamp incorrectly! If used properly, there's no issue. Stop not using xyz because you "heard about ...", instead educate yourself on the issue so you can avoid it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sorry I will revise my question a little, I didn't mean to bash op-amps I just have never used them before and wanted to know if it was even a good idea to try or if there was some obvious reason I missed.

Comment: Modulating IR LED with analog signal is not good idea. Emmiting radiation is not lineary depended of current, running through diode.

Comment: @user263983 Do you mean from a distortion point of view? I'm not super worried about a perfectly reconstructed signal, a little distortion might even sound cooler than the original

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Great to see that you're excited about electronics and are keen to learn to make something new. What's your knowledge level, situation and background in electronics? Without knowing your capabilities, it's difficult to answer you well. Again, welcome.

Comment: No, I meant received signal may be completely different from sent. Waveform will be another.

Comment: Wrong qustion. Rather than imagine a circuit, you will do better to imagine the result and write a spec for waveform, voltage and current of the LED and the effect you desire.

Comment: @user263983 your claim is pretty questionable. The emission intensity is pretty proportional to the current flowing through an LED. Are you maybe mixing up voltage and current? But even then, "distortion" describes the effect accurately...

Comment: @TonyM My knowledge level is pretty low, I've taken some introductory electronics classes in college, but it was all digital, so I am completely out of my element here. I'll update my question to include that. Thank you for the warm welcome!

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Could you point me to an example of a spec? I'll try to see if I can rephrase to make it clearer.

Comment: never seen a spec for what you are imagining so tell us what you imagine it to look like with details. That example was pretty distorted

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I added my best short at a spec, let me know what you think, and thanks for your help

Comment: Basically you want to use an optical medium to act as an audio transmitter in the presence of electrical ambient  light.  This determines your basic SNR . Optical filtering can improve this immensely. Going to another wavelength like Infrared or UV can make massive improvements with a built in daylight blocking filter.  So going forward decide what SNR you really want, knowing that a good cell phone can range about I guess 30 dB while old digital landlines were > 70dB SNR and you probably need at least 15 dB to barely hear conversation with some errors.   FL and LED ambient lights =very noisy.

Comment: So you decide on objectives for SNR and environment to determine what technology is needed. BTW those are nice indicator LEDs around 1000 mcd +/-50% depending on colour, I have RGBYW in  mono colour 5mm LEDs that are > 16,000 mcd and some whites > 30,000 mcd in 30 deg. vs 50deg ( which spreads more but reduces intensity about 50%. Surplus from my former business in the thousands

Comment: Your comfort with *digital* suggests that the AD9833-Arduino-LED signal chain should be mostly digital. The analog output of AD9833 might require a simple gain stage to take 0.6v peak-to-peak sine wave up to a level that Arduino's analog-to-digital converter accepts nicely. Then the Arduino uses Pulse-Width-Modulator to generate a digital output that drives a LED through a series resistor. PWM frequency would be above 25 kHz. If this seems attractive, I could attempt an "answer".

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Ah ok I see what you're saying, thank you. So if I were to select say a 30dB SNR as my desired spec, I would then just have to should the op-amp I need? Once I have that, would my latest schematic work?

Comment: @glen_geek I was hoping to keep it digital, but (and I'm sorry for not including it in the original question) I am actually looking to drive an array of LEDs (16 RGB leds). From what I understand most microcontrollers can't source enough current to drive more than a few LEDs, which is why I'm looking at the 48-channel LED driver from TI. Is it still possible to accomplish this with purely digital components and another type of driver? If so I would really like to see your answer. I'll amend my question again.

Comment: Your problem must be broken down into components for optocoupling. Consider a PD is 0.5uA/uW and your optical power depends on distance, size of detector, capacitance and BW.  The CTR for a tightly couple optoisolator is typically <1. Your Can use Friis  Loss from the gap to detector with ambient optical noise determines your CTR which depends on path loss. So you end up only sampling a very small % of radiated power. a  Transimpedance amplifier with high gain and audio BW compromises your SNR. So specify the parameters needed for each stage and consider LEDs >30 times brighter for Iv @ same I

Comment: Rather than trial and error, simulate with specs 1st

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choice of **common-cathode** red-green-blue LEDs means that an *analog* LED driver should drive LED current into the open LED anode. The common LED cathode would go to 0V (GND).
But most signal sources provide output *relative to ground*. This makes driving a cathode-grounded LED with current a bit more complex. Your AD9833 signal source is of this type. Many microphones are too.

Your LED suggests maximum current of 30mA. This means that with no AC signal, it should idle at half-current, at 15mA. Then it can swing down toward zero mA, and up toward 30mA with signal current. The LED would appear constantly bright, because your eye cannot see rapid signal swings at frequencies above 30 Hz. Average current remains at about 15 mA.

An analog driver, driving a cathode-grounded LED might look like the two-transistor circuit (below). Resistor bias is chosen so that most any LED would have roughly 15mA flowing with no input signal, provided the DC supply voltage is +5V. Input voltage to C1 would be about 0.65V peak-to-peak AC signal.
[image: 15mA LED driver]

----------

Driving common-cathode LED array is simpler with a PWM signal source. You only have to calculate LED current for two cases:

- LED **OFF**: 0 mA current
- LED **ON**: 30 mA current

A transistor saturated switch toggles between these two cases, driven from a digital signal source. An Arduino with a Vdd supply of +5V would toggle a digital output pin between two voltages: 0V & +5V. This signal would drive a switching transistor ON or OFF.
Current from the Arduino pin is small (1.4 mA), limited by a resistor (R1, below). Another resistor (R2) is chosen to limit LED current to 30 mA, from a +5v DC supply. The transistor has ample current gain and is actually over-driven so that it acts as an ON/OFF switch. Note that the 30 mA current through transistor and LED does not flow from the microcontroller, but does flow back to the +5V supply. Many PWM outputs could drive such a switch before microcontroller current limits are exceeded.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkfz72.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

 A PWM signal of 50% duty cycle would drive the LED **ON** to 30 mA half the time, and drive the LED **OFF** to 0 mA half the time. The average is 15 mA.

Converting an analog waveform input to PWM signal is done with software inside Arduino, which uses its *analog-to-digital converter* (ADC) to provide to its PWM module a digital input. The PWM module would be set for a frequency above the audio range for your application (above 20 kHz).
Most of these microcontroller ADCs use +Vdd as a reference voltage, so that input signal ranging between `0 -to- +5V` gives an output value between `0 -to- 256` for an 8-bit ADC, for example.
A program might read ADC 20,000 times per second, convert this number to a range compatible with PWM range, and write to the PWM duty cycle register.

---

Driving multiple LEDs with one transistor switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ze3A.png)</sup>
The MOSfet would be selected from data sheet to have less than about one ohm \$RDS_{on}\$. A "logic level" MOSfet would be preferred, especially if the microcontroller was run at a supply voltage lower than +5V. The MOSfet should not run hot with only 90mA being switched on/off.

Since the switched 90mA current is reasonably high, a DC supply bypass capacitor should be placed near the resistor common point, and MOSfet source (which is grounded). This should reduce radiated EMI interference.

When you drive multiple LEDs with **ONE** PWM switch like this, each LED is modulated with the SAME PWM signal. If you want each LED to have *individually-controlled* modulation, each LED would require its own PWM channel, and its own MOSfet. Some microcontrollers have multiple PWMs on board.

Comment: First, thank you for the detailed response, this helps immensely. I really appreciate the time you took to explain everything for a n00b like myself. As for driving an LED array, I have two questions: first, can I just place additional LEDs in parallel below the transistor? If not, what would be the basic idea for turning this into an array? And second, I haven't much experience with the ADC on an Arduino, do you think it could handle 4 separate function generators? I'm looking to emulate a guitar a bit, so I was hoping I could overlap some note frequencies on top of each other. Ty again

Comment: The *analog driver* described above drives **ONE** LED only...if you add a RED LED in parallel, each LED gets roughly half the current (and generates half the light). If you add a GREEN LED or a BLUE LED in parallel with a RED LED, the red one hogs all the current, leaving none (or very very little) for the other colour. For the *PWM switch* driver, a single transistor can drive multiple LEDs, if each LED has its own series resistor (schematic edit pending).

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified which driver I was talking about, but you fully answered me for both so thank you. I didn't even know about the red LED current hogging - that's really good to know. For some reason I thought the driver would compensate/adapt for a bigger "load" of LEDs but now I see that I was thinking a little too hard about it! Thank you again so much for taking the time to so clearly and fully answer my question.